# Figgle Fonts Is Installed But Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I installed `Figgle Fonts` which lets you turn text into ACSII inside of C# and with more customization, Using NUget, I restarted `Visual Studio 2022` but it wont recognize the syntax.

[image]

The Error

[image]

Comment: How did you install the NuGet package ? Do you see it in the dependencies node under you project, in Solution Explorer ? 
You could try right clicking your solution in Solution Explorer and hit Restore NuGet Packages, and don't forget to use the FiggleFonts namespace (using on top of the file).

Comment: Yo thank you so much im so dumb i forgot to do:  using Figgle; Thanks Again!